# Jenkins does not find my git repository in Visual Studio Online

Tags: git, jenkins, azure-devops

I have a Visual Studio Online project working with Git. Everything works fine from inside Visual Studio. I'm trying then to configure a Jenkins job that gets the code from this project, but without success. Although the URL and the credentials are correct, Jenkins gives me this error on the job configuration page:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h https://[username]:[pwd]@[domain].visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/[project] HEAD" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: fatal: repository 'https://[username]:[pwd]@[domain].visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/[project]/' not found

If I save and try to build, the build fails with the following error:

```
unable to access 'HTTP://https:///[username]:[pwd]@[domain].visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/[project]/': Could not resolve host: https
```

Does anyone have any idea on what can I do?

Thanks

Comment: On the Jenkins server, are you able to clone your Git project with the https URL? Did you try with a ssh URL?

Comment: I have Visual Studio installed on the Jenkins server. On Visual Studio, I can clone the project using the HTTPS url, but on Jenkins the same url does not work.

Comment: It's a private Git URL? Are you using some credentials with Jenkins to access this URL?

Comment: What do you mean by "private Git URL"? If you mean an internal server, it is not. It is Visual Studio Online. I've tried to follow the steps documented here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/jenkins-and-vso-vs.aspx

Comment: Private Git URL = you need some credentials to access it. As I understand, you are using your Visual Studio Online to access this URL. Did you try to launch a git command line like (with DOS): git clone https://....?

Comment: Ok, it is a private URL. I need the credentials.
When trying to perform the clone in command line, I have some scenarios: a) Using the URL without embedding the credentials: GIT prompts me for the credentials and when I provide them, it works. b) Using the URL embedding the credentials: does not work. This is the error message: "fatal: repository [url] not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally made Jenkins perform the clone of a Visual Studio Online git repository.

The [official Microsoft documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/jenkins-and-vso-vs.aspx) is wrong. Jenkins and the Git plugin do not work as they explain there. In order to the clone operation to work, I had to put on the repository URL field the same URL used for clone in Visual Studio: https://[domain].visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_git/[project].

Additionaly, I had to add a credential on Jenkins with the username and password for the connection to be successful. I am using the alternate credentials in Visual Studio Online.

Thanks for all the help.